# XAMPP Images Not Showing/Broken (- Possibly .htaccess)

Tags: windows, image, apache, .htaccess, xampp

I am hosting a website on the localhost of a VPS using XAMPP.

When I go to the website be it on the VPS directly through localhost or remotely from my own computer - images are not loading and appearing as broken and when I try to view the image directly I am given an error 404 and object not found.

The image paths are completely correct in corresponding to htdocs.

For example,

```
http://mysite.com/icons/pixels.gif
```

I copied that link, checked htdocs and that is exactly where the image should be yet I am given an error 404 and object not found.

HOWEVER.

Out of chance I changed the \icons\ from an 'i' to a capital and the image loaded normally. The icons folder in htdocs does not have a capital letter.

The problem may be my .htaccess file though, here is a link to it: http://pastebin.com/vUnhjb2A

Comment: That's .. very odd behavior indeed. Do you have any htaccess rules that may have caused this? They can be in httpd.conf aswell.

Comment: Or perhaps this forum post is related to your issue? www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?t=6481

Comment: Hi David, I just followed that forum post to the letter - nothing.

Also, I'm not very sure about my .htaccess

Perhaps you could check ? This is a complete copy:

http://pastebin.com/vUnhjb2A

Comment: It's hard to read in the comments section, perhaps put it in the original post? However, the RewriteUrl ^home/(.*) could have something to do with it.

Comment: Hi David, I just edited the comment and posted the link to a copy on PasteBin, hopefully that will help.

Comment: I would try removing any rule that matches everything and see if that helps. If not, report back here.